# Groups match with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have something like this :

```
Some info_a
Useless info
sub_info_a
Useless info

Some info_b
Useless info
sub_info_b_1
sub_info_b_2
Useless info

Some info_c
Useless info
sub_info_c
Useless info
```

I want to create groups so that I can have something like this :

```py
(info_a, sub_info_a), (info_b, sub_info_b_1, sub_info_b_2), (info_c, sub_info_c)
```

I tried :

```py
^Some (info_\w+) .*$\n.*$\n(?:^(sub_info_\w+) .*$\n)+
```

But it only matches the last sub_info_b

```py
(info_a, sub_info_a), (info_b, sub_info_b_2), (info_c, sub_info_c)
```

I also tried :

```py
^Some (info_\w+) .*$\n.*$\n|^(sub_info_\w+) .*$\n
```

This one gave me :

```
('info_a', ''), ('', 'sub_info_a'), ('info_b', ''), ('', 'sub_info_b_1'), ('', 'sub_info_b_2'), ('info_c', ''), ('', 'sub_info_c')
```

Which is not really what I want.
Note that sub_info can appear more than once or twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^Some (info_\w+).*\n.*\n((?:^sub_info_\w+.*\n)+)
```

The capture group should be *around* the quantified non-capture group. When you quantify a capture group, it just captures the last occurrence. So you need to put a group around that to capture all the repetitions.

Note that this will not put each repetition into separate groups in the result -- there's always a 1-to-1 correspondence between capture groups and `.group(n)` items in the result. You need to split up the second capture group when processing the results of the regexp.

I've also removed the space before `.*`, and there's no need for both `\n` and `$`.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pofeEp/1)